# How to SQL distinct on only one column

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, distinct

I'm trying to apply `DISTINCT` on only one column.

The question is:

> Who is ordering equipment where the description begins with "tennis" or "volleyball".
>
> Include:
>
> 1. Customer number,
> 2. Stock number, and
> 3. Description
>
> Do not repeat any rows.

This is what the tables look like: [`Items`, `Stock`, `Orders`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqwHa.jpg)

This is my code:

```
select distinct 
    orders.customer_num, stock.stock_num, stock.description
from 
    orders
join 
    items on items.order_num = orders.order_num
join 
    stock on stock.stock_num = items.stock_num
where 
    stock.description like 'tennis%' 
    or stock.description like 'volleyball%';
```

The result is:

[image: Result of Query]

But I'm trying to get no repeating numbers on the `CUSTOMER_NUM` column.

Thank you..

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you want to aggregate other columns?

Comment: pl specify the kind of output you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your join condition is wrong.please try joining item table to customer table with condition as items.customer_num =customer.customer_num .I am not sure whether it will work as we dont have correct data of these tables.

Comment: It yields the same results using the customer table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll see this, but I don't believe the rows aren't repeating. Look at the description. You're only getting one different item description per customer number which don't repeat for that customer number. You can see this by adding in: 'order by orders.customer_num, stock.stock_num;' to the end.